# If LEN(Sheet1.Range("A1") > 0) Returning 0, But Still Running Code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an If ElseIf statement that is not working as intended. Below is a sample of the code that I am working with:

```
If LEN(Sheet1.Range("A1") > 0) Then
     Do something

ElseIf LEN(Sheet1.Range("A2") > 0) Then
     Do something
```

The problem is that even when the length of A1 is 0 and the length of A2 is greater than 0 (which I have tested many times), the first If statement runs and completely ignores the ElseIf statement. I also set up a Debug.Print(LEN(Sheet1.Range("A1"))) statement under the first If statement and that also returns 0 in the console. I am not quite sure where the error is.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I think you mean `If Len(Sheet1.Range("A1")) > 0 Then` . The comparison should not be a part of the Len function.

Comment: As pointed out, the expression was evaluating `TRUE` or `FALSE` inside the `LEN` function. The expression was cast into a String `"True"` or `"False"` which would cause `LEN` to return string lengths of 4 or 5. So the statement was `If 4 Then` or `If 5 Then` the if statement will evaluate any non-zero number as TRUE, and therefore run the code. Funny interactions of different parts of VBA trying to be smart and interpretive.

Comment: Thank you so much @ChristoferWeber! That solved my problem. Not sure why I wrote it the way I did haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following:

```
Sub Button_Click()
    If Len(Sheet1.Range("A1")) > 0 Then MsgBox "A1"
    If Len(Sheet1.Range("A2")) > 0 Then MsgBox "A2"
End Sub
```

The comparison must be outside the `Len` function, and you should not use `elseif` in this scenario.